# Punctuation spacing at the end of equation, align or $$

Tags: spacing, equations, punctuation

In writing equations, I use to end with commas, dots and whatsoever punctuation separated by a `\quad` spacer...

```
\begin{equation}
      sin(x)+cos(x)=a\quad,
\end{equation}
```

Since I am going to write tons and tons of lines of mathematical expressions, I would like to automatically implement this spacing every time I decide to put punctuation {, . ; ! ? etc.} at the end of `equation`, `align` `$$` and so on and so forth.

Does anybody have an idea?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Typographically, this is not good practice. In some rare case, you may add a `thin space`  for better readability, certainly not an `em space`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While various people eschew the practice (I've been berated by editors on this site, though my local editor accepts the practice), I too prefer the extra space between the equation and the subsequent punctuation.

I prefer to `\rlap` the punctuation with the desired spacing, so that it does not alter the overall centered alignment of the equation content.  This would otherwise be most noticeable when there are unpunctuated equations in the vicinity of punctuated ones. (**Note: I would find this aspect useful even if punctuation is inserted *without* additional spacing.**)

The particular style of desired spacing may be defined in the macros `\mcomma` and `\mperiod`.

I make the `\rlap` part of the optional argument though, for those cases where the equation content is so wide that the lapped punctuation would interfere with the numbering.  In those cases a blank optional argument `[]` will cause the punctuation to be inserted without an `\rlap`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\mperiod[1][\rlap]{#1{\;\;\;.}}
\newcommand\mcomma[1][\rlap]{#1{\;\;\;,}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
y &= mx + b\mcomma\\
y &= Ax^2 + Bx + C\mperiod
\end{align*}
Also,
\[
F = ma
\]
and
\[
E = mc^2
\mperiod\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't believe full automation is possible, because of the multiple meanings of both a period and a comma in math mode...it would be near impossible to differentiate a decimal point from a grammatical period in some cases.

However, one could use a compact notation, such as `\z.` and `\z,` (or the optional `\z[].` and `\z[],`), as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\z[2][\rlap]{\ifx.#2\mperiod[#1]\else\ifx,#2\mcomma[#1]\fi\fi}
\newcommand\mperiod[1][\rlap]{#1{\;\;\;.}}
\newcommand\mcomma[1][\rlap]{#1{\;\;\;,}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
y &= mx + b\z,\\
y &= Ax^2 + Bx + C\z.
\end{align*}
Also,
\[
F = ma
\]
and
\[
E = mc^2
\z.\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It seems that we have to go through manual insertion in any case... but your compact notation is nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `newcommand` that takes two parameters:

1. Equation
2. Punctuation

If punctuation is not provided, do not add `\quad` and if it is provided, add `\quad`.

Here is a simple MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\myequation}[2]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{%
\begin{equation}
  #1
\end{equation}%
}{%
\begin{equation}
  #1 \quad #2
\end{equation}%
}%
}%

\begin{document}
\myequation{\sin(x)+\cos(x)=a}{,}
\myequation{\sin(x)+\cos(x)=b}{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the itlalics is introduced by equation environment. You mean to say I have to replace it with `\sin`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks :). I have edited my answer.

Comment: Approved your code :-)